# How to decorate a python class and override a method?

Tags: python, decorator

I have a class

```
class A:
     def sample_method():
```

I would like to decorate class A `sample_method()` and override the contents of `sample_method()`

```
class DecoratedA(A):
    def sample_method():
```

The setup above resembles inheritance, but I need to keep the preexisting instance of class A when the decorated function is used.

```
a # preexisting instance of class A
decorated_a = DecoratedA(a)
decorated_a.functionInClassA() #functions in Class A called as usual with preexisting instance
decorated_a.sample_method() #should call the overwritten sample_method() defined in DecoratedA
```

What is the proper way to go about this?

Comment: Hi welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please tell us what exactly you are trying to do because I suspect this is an [X/Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and you don't actually need to do the specific thing you described.

Comment: This isn't decoration; it *is* inheritance, where you simply pass an instance of `A` as an argument to the subclass `DecoratedA` (which is closer to something like a copy constructor in C++). Everything else works as you expect: non-overidden methods don't change, and overrides are called instead of the inherited method. All of which is to say, you need to define `DecoratedA` correctly to initialize your new instance from the existing one.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a straightforward way to do what you're asking. Generally, after an instance has been created, it's too late to mess with the methods its class defines.

There are two options you have, as far as I see it. Either you create a wrapper or proxy object for your pre-existing instance, or you modify the instance to change its behavior.

A proxy defers most behavior to the object itself, while only adding (or overriding) some limited behavior of its own:

```
class Proxy:
    def __init__(self, obj):
        self.obj = obj

    def overridden_method(self):     # add your own limited behavior for a few things
        do_stuff()

    def __getattr__(self, name):     # and hand everything else off to the other object
        return getattr(self.obj, name)
```

`__getattr__` isn't perfect here, it can only work for regular methods, not special `__dunder__` methods that are often looked up directly in the class itself. If you want your proxy to match all possible behavior, you probably need to add things like `__add__` and `__getitem__`, but that might not be necessary in your specific situation (it depends on what `A` does).

As for changing the behavior of the existing object, one approach is to write your subclass, and then change the existing object's class to be the subclass. This is a little sketchy, since you won't have ever initialized the object as the new class, but it might work if you're only modifying method behavior.

```
class ModifiedA(A):
    def overridden_method(self):     # do the override in a normal subclass
        do_stuff()

def modify_obj(obj):                 # then change an existing object's type in place!
    obj.__class__ = ModifiedA        # this is not terribly safe, but it can work
```

You could also consider adding an instance variable that would shadow the method you want to override, rather than modifying `__class__`. Writing the function could be a little tricky, since it won't get bound to the object automatically when called (that only happens for functions that are attributes of a class, not attributes of an instance), but you could probably do the binding yourself (with `partial` or `lambda` if you need to access `self`.

Answer (score 0):

First, why not just define it from the beginning, how you want it, instead of decorating it?

Second, why not decorate the method itself?

To answer the question:
You can reassign it

```
class A:
     def sample_method(): ...
pass
A.sample_method = DecoratedA.sample_method;
```

but that affects every instance.

Another solution is to reassign the method for just one object.

```
import functools;
a.sample_method = functools.partial(DecoratedA.sample_method, a);
```

Another solution is to (temporarily) change the type of an existing object.

```
a = A();
a.__class__ = DecoratedA;
a.sample_method();
a.__class__ = A;
```